# Android soft keyboard creates space in all fragments above activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-keypad, fragmentmanager

I am having an activity with a view pager which has four pages. In `page1`, I click on a view which opens another fragment above it. Now this fragment has `edittext` when user click on it for typing, the `soft keyboard opens` and it takes lot of time resizing the layout. I found out that keyboard is creating space in all the `backstack fragments` and that's why current fragment is taking this much time. Can you please suggest **how can I force android keyboard to create space only in current fragment not in all fragments above the activity**.

Comment: check here please: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Comment: I don't know where you heard that, but its totally inaccurate.  Bringing up the soft keyboard only causes a relayout of the current screen.

Comment: @gabe-sechan may be I am incorrect but could you please correct me then why the keyboard takes so much time to relayout in fragment and same process with same layout in activity is quite fast.